# CodeIgniter Pagination is not working with routing

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I want to show all users page wise initially. So if I browse `http://mydomain/user` it will redirect to `http://mydomain/user/page/1` and so on. But if I browse `http://mydomain/user/1` it will show only single user with id of user.

`http://mydomain/user/1` >> it works fine. But as I want pagination so I want to redirect `http://mydomain/user` to `http://mydomain/user/page/1` always

My Routing Info is:

```
$route['user/(:num)'] = 'user/index/$1';
$route['user'] = 'user/page/$1';
```

But when I pressed to `http://mydomain/user` it does not rout to `user/page/$1`. I have index() method which output to single user information if I give slug. so get a page wise list I used routing and page method. But it is not working. it gives `404 Page not found`

Could anybody have solution please..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the manual for routing:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

As far as i can see your second route doesn´t make much sense, you are calling the method page() of your User class - and trying to pass in $1 which does not exist. I think you need to explain better what you want to achieve with your second route - I don´t really see why you need it at all at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution.
$route['user'] = 'user/page'; and in page class i redirect to redirect('user/page/1');